# warning in maya: 'cannot make assignment', why?

Tags: python, render, maya

I found an error like this is 
'Warning: line 1: Node **'*BLABLABLA*.instObjGroups[0]': cannot make assignment to '*BLABLABLAB_SG*' shader.
'**
I've searched various forums, but haven't found a solution. maybe someone can help me cause the error and how to overcome it.
thank you very much for help: D

Answer (score 0):

i came on this error recently because I wasn't use the command cmds.shadingNode('blinn' ,as=True) instead of just cmds.createNode